# How to add a lifecycle to a Thread that starts with "new Thread(new Runnable)..."?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Most examples of lifecycles for a Thread tend to be about threads in which you first instantiate them some way:

Thread t = new Thread();

Then you can refer to that thread in the lifecycle by saying stuff like:

t.join();

or something like that.

But how to do add the proper lifecyle when you have not physically instantiated the Thread, such as you start:
new Thread(new Runnable)...

Comment: "when you have not physically instantiated the Thread, such as you start: new Thread(new Runnable)" -- that is as much "physically instantiated" as is `new Thread()`.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking:  What does "add a lifecycle" mean?  If you are asking whether a thread can be started more than one time, the answer is, "No!"

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Before instantiation of thread");
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Thread State ::" + Thread.currentThread().getState());
            for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.println("Thread State ::" +i);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("Thread State ::" + Thread.currentThread().getState());
            }
        }
    }).start();
    System.out.println("After instantiation of thread");
}
```

Comment: You can not set the state without thread instantiate, Also request you to add code snippet which you are trying to do ?

Comment: Please clarify what this code does and why it answers the question. A block of code can this size isn't a great answer on it's own.

Comment: I agree, just trying to show yhwang that it is not possible.

Comment: _You can not set the state without thread instantiate_  How does this answer show that?  This example _does_ instantiate a thread, and then it makes no attempt to change the thread's state.  What is that supposed to prove?

Comment: Hey James , please try in your IDE there is no support of setting state for thread.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for responding promptly. I guess what I'm trying to ask is: because I start the thread as new Thread(new Runnable...), I find myself unable to do stuff as in the following code: public void pause() {
        isItOk = false;
        while (true) {
            try {
                t.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
        t = null;
    }

    public void resume() {
        isItOk = true;
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

Comment: to continue previous post: On that example, t stands for a Thread because I was clearly able to define it somewhere. But if didn't do that because I started with new Thread(new Runnable)..., then waht should I do? How can I manipulate thread on resume, pause, stop, etc.   What I want is for the program not to crash eventually.